# How to return a Mono<ResponseEntity> where the response entity can be of two different types

Tags: functional-programming, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am new to Spring Webflux / Reactor Core and am trying to perform the following functionality:

1. call userservice.LoginWebApp()
2. If a user is returned, return ResponseEntity of type "User". If empty, Return ResponseEntity of type "String"

The following code gives a type error as .defaultIfEmpty() expects ResponseEntity of type user. Can you please advise on the correct operator / method to implement this functionality.

```
@PostMapping("api/user/login/webApp")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> login(@RequestBody Credentials credentials, ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
     return userService.loginWebApp(credentials, serverWebExchange)
             .map(user -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(user))
             .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Invalid username or password"));
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `cast` operator to downcast out of the generic, and I believe WebFlux will still be able to marshal the `User` and the `String`:

```
@PostMapping("api/user/login/webApp")
public Mono<ResponseEntity> login(@RequestBody Credentials credentials, ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
     return userService.loginWebApp(credentials, serverWebExchange)
             .map(user -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(user))
             .cast(ResponseEntity.class)
             .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Invalid username or password"));
}
```

Comment: Hi Simon. I have a similar question but i am very new about webflux so i couldn't find any example so could you help me about my question below.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059178/how-to-combine-responseentity-with-flux-or-mono-for-crud-operations

Comment: The great API created by @Simon has evolved and these days we can use just: `.map(ResponseEntity::ok).defaultIfEmpty(...);`

Comment: I was checking for Junits for webflux and found this helpful. 

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-header

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211452/how-to-junit-test-a-method-with-mono-return-type

Answer (score 2):

I would do the following:

1. Make a base class for responses

   ```
   abstract class Response {
   }
   ```
2. Make separate classes for every kind of response (like UserResponse, ErrorResponse, NotFoundResponse etc) and extend them from the base `Response` class

   ```
   class UserResponse extends Response {
       private String login;
       private String password;

       public UserResponse(String login, String password) {
           this.login = login;
           this.password = password;
       }

       @JsonGetter("login")
       public String getLogin() {
           return login;
       }

       @JsonSetter("login")
       public void setLogin(String login) {
           this.login = login;
       }

       @JsonGetter("password")
       public String getPassword() {
           return password;
       }

       @JsonSetter("password")
       public void setPassword(String password) {
           this.password = password;
       }
   }

   class ErrorResponse extends Response {
       private String errorMessage;

       public ErrorResponse(String errorMessage) {
           this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
       }

       @JsonGetter("error_message")
       public String getErrorMessage() {
           return errorMessage;
       }

       @JsonSetter("error_message")
       public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
           this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Explicitly set the type of return value `Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>>`
   And that's it.

   ```
   @GetMapping("/test/{login}")
   public Mono<ResponseEntity<Response>> test(@PathVariable(value = "login") String login) {
       return loginWebApp(login)
               .map(userResponse -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(userResponse))
               .defaultIfEmpty(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(new ErrorResponse("bad login")));
   }
   ```

Now let's try it with bad login:

[image: bad login]

And good login:

[image: good login]

Full code can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/8hADcM4X)

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Could you tell me about how i can apply this solution to Flux? 
i have a question here if you can help me i will be glad.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65059178/how-to-combine-responseentity-with-flux-or-mono-for-crud-operations