# How to combine ResponseEntity with Flux or Mono For CRUD operations

Tags: java, spring-webflux

Hi i am trying to create a CRUD controller with repository but i couldn't find any example for using as reference. I want to do something like this below.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/open/books", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public ResponseEntity<Flux<Book>> getBooks() {

            Flux<Book> books = bookRepository.findAll();
            // if books is null 
                       return new ResponseEntity<Flux<Book>>(books, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            // else
                       return new ResponseEntity<Flux<Book>>(books, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/open/books", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
        public ResponseEntity<Mono<Book>> updateBook(@RequestBody Book bookObject) {

            Mono<Book> book = bookRepository.findById(bookObject.getId());
            // if book is null 
                       return new ResponseEntity<Flux<Book>>(books, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
            // else
                       bookRepository.save(book);
                       return new ResponseEntity<Flux<Book>>(books, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

I have tried something like this but it is always returning OK because Flux or Mono object itself isn't null but it's data is null i couldn't find how to check it.

```
Flux<Book> books = bookRepository.findAll();
 HttpStatus status = books != null ? HttpStatus.OK : HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;
```

Comment: I have same issue too

Comment: i did a simple google search for "spring webflux crud" and i got 100s of hits. Here is the first https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-crud-with-spring-webflux-5606a0fccc31 voted to close