# How to junit test a method with Mono return type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, mono, spring-test, mockmvc

What is the proper way to junit mono and get a body response?
I expected "Single Item Only" to be in the body response of MockHttpServletResponse. But instead I see it's returned in Async.

**Sample Method:**

```
public Mono<String> getData(final String data) {
    return this.webClient.get().uri("/dataValue/" + data)
        .retrieve()
        .bodyToMono(String.class);
}
```

**Sample Junit:**

```
@WebMvcTest(DataController.class)
public class DataMockTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private Service service;

@Test
public void getDataTest() throws Exception {

Mono<String> strMono = Mono.just("Single Item Only");

when(service.getData("DATA")).thenReturn(strMono);

this.mockMvc.perform(get("/some/rest/toget/data")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status()
        .isOk());
}
```

**Test Response:**

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = GET
      Request URI = /some/rest/toget/data
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Accept:"application/json"]
             Body = null
    Session Attrs = {}

Async:
    Async started = true
     Async result = Single Item Only

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 200
    Error message = null
          Headers = []
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

**Updated Junit with StepVerifier:**

```
@WebMvcTest(DataController.class)
public class DataMockTest {

  @Autowired
  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @MockBean
  private Service service;

@Test
public void getDataTest() throws Exception {

Mono<String> strMono = Mono.just("Single Item Only");

when(service.getData("DATA")).thenReturn(strMono);

//Added this which verifies the mono method. How to mock it so the API would return the mono value?
StepVerifier.create(service.getDATA("DATA"))
    .assertNext(data -> {
      assertNotNull(data);
      assertEquals("Single Item Only", data);
    }).verifyComplete();


this.mockMvc.perform(get("/some/rest/toget/data")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
    .andDo(print())
    .andExpect(status()
        .isOk());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that what you are looking forward is StepVerifier. With it you cam assert the content of Mono an Flux data types. Please refer to https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher.

Comment: Is there not a way where I can mock to perform a get to the api I am trying to test?
I was able to use stepVerifier to assert the mono data. Added in post.

Comment: Now I am confused. What do you want to test and what do you want to mock? Do you want to assert the body of the response?

Comment: Yes, get api -> /some/rest/toget/data should return a body response.

Comment: In that case you will need to use “andExpect” as explained in https://www.baeldung.com/integration-testing-in-spring#2-verify-response-body.