# How to change response HTTP status of Spring WebClient

Tags: spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have got a situation that is needed to return HTTP 2XX when WebClient returns any kind of 4XX.

My existing code below,

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<>String> postMethodA(String valueA) {
  
   return webClient
          .put()
          .uri'/')
          .bodyValue(valueA)
          .retrieve()
          .toEntity(String.class);
}
```

I added onStatus method like this.

```
public Mono<ResponseEntity<>String> postMethodA(String valueA) {
  
   return webClient
          .put()
          .uri'/')
          .bodyValue(valueA)
          .retrieve()
          .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4XXClientError response -> Mono.empty())
          .toEntity(String.class);
}
```

If I added

```
onStatus(HttpStatus::is4XXClientError response -> Mono.empty())
```

still, it is not gonna work because it is not able to return 2XX.

Is there a way to change the Http status when returning the response? and can you please show some example?

Comment: Could you check if this can answer your question ?? —> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49868246/how-to-return-a-monoresponseentity-where-the-response-entity-can-be-of-two-dif#

Comment: I don't understand the question. You consume some endpoint `/` and want to do what? Which response should be changed?

Answer (score 1):

> To ignore an error response completely, and propagate neither response
> nor error, use a filter, or add onErrorResume downstream, for example:

```
 webClient.get()
     .uri("https://someUrl.com/account/123")
     .retrieve()
     .bodyToMono(Account.class)
     .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
          ex -> ex.getRawStatusCode() == 404 ? Mono.empty() : Mono.error(ex));
```

Reference: [JavaDoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/WebClient.ResponseSpec.html#onStatus-java.util.function.Predicate-java.util.function.Function-)